# Partial git apply

Tags: git

How can I get `git apply --index` to not abort completely just because a single hunk fails? I have a 100K+ patch with dozens of files deleted and added, it'd be a pain to do the `patch -p1`, `git add`, `git rm` dance manually.

Edit:  `git apply --reject --index` seems to do two thirds of the work: the patch is applied and removed files are staged for deletion but new files are not added.

Comment: does the `--apply` flag in combination with `--reject` help at all?

Comment: just wondering, is it possible to use `git am --interactive` with this patch ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since git version 1.7.12, [`git apply` has a `--3way` (or `-3`) option](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) which will:

1. Apply any changes it can figure out and stage them (i.e.: add them to the working tree and index),
2. Add any new files and stage them (i.e.: add them to the working tree and index), and,
3. When it encounters a merge conflict, it will, for each conflicting hunk:

   1. Put the code from the branch you are patching between `<<<<<<< ours` and `=======` markers, and,
   2. Put the code from the patch file between `=======` and `>>>>>>> theirs` markers.

   ... files with conflicts will not be staged: you'll have to manually fix them and `git add` them afterwards.

Answer (score 14):

This is what I do,

First, perform `git apply --reject`. Then run `git add -p` and select hunks interactively. Instead of `add -p` you can also use other git GUIs. For adding new files add them manually if not added.

Answer (score 9):

Try `git apply --reject <patchfile>`