# Resolve conflict between two files that not in a git repository

Tags: git

I like git's way of resolving conflict and I wanna use it for two versions of an arbitrary file, that are not in a repository. Any suggestion about what could be the approach?

Comment: Use a text merge/diff application? There is Meld (cross-OS) and WinMerge (windows) for example and others. You pick two files and see the diff between them. You can then try to reconcile the differences. Git isn't even doing anything new, it's *the same* mechanism, but the two files are just the old and new (or alternative) version of the same file.

Comment: @VLAZ Actually yes... Seem like i did not ask the true question. Seems like git just triggers default merge/diff application. I am more into doing it on server shell. So going with vimdiff is best option for me.

Comment: linked question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796528/partial-git-apply

Answer (score 1):

If you want to partially transform the content of `thefile` from `A` to `B`, you can maybe take advantage of `git add -p` which runs from the command line :

- create an empty repository
- create a commit with `thefile` having content `A`
- copy `thefile` with content `B` into the repo
- use `git add -p` to have the interactive command line interface to stage the diff chunk by chunk
- once you are satisfied with the staged content, commit, and discard the other changes

---

a technical note : for a merge git actually has *3* files : `ours`, `theirs` and `base`. A conflict can arise when a *patch* (the diff between two files: `base` and `theirs`) tries to apply a diff in a position where the file has already changed in the 3rd file (`ours`).